# Split HTML value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
    // JavaScript Document   
    calc = function(prodNum) {
    var total = prices[0];
    Vstarterkit = (document.getElementById("starterkit").value);

T1 = (document.getElementById("doorswitch").value * prices[1]);
    T2 = (document.getElementById("passiveir").value * prices[2]);
T3 = (document.getElementById("vibration").value * prices[3]);
T4 =  (document.getElementById("keyfob").value * prices[4]);
T5 =  (document.getElementById("keypad").value * prices[5]);
T6 = (document.getElementById("communicator").value * prices[6]);
T7 = (document.getElementById("linebox").value * prices[7]);


    total += (document.getElementById("doorswitch").value * prices[1]);
total += (document.getElementById("passiveir").value * prices[2]);
total += (document.getElementById("vibration").value * prices[3]);
total += (document.getElementById("keyfob").value * prices[4]);
total += (document.getElementById("keypad").value * prices[5]);
total += (document.getElementById("communicator").value * prices[6]);
total += (document.getElementById("linebox").value * prices[7]);
    total += (document.getElementById("starterkit").value * 1);



  document.getElementById("Total_Cost").innerHTML = ""+total+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = ""+Vstarterkit+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C1").innerHTML = ""+prices[1]+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C1").innerHTML = ""+prices[1]+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C2").innerHTML = ""+prices[2]+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C3").innerHTML = ""+prices[3]+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C4").innerHTML = ""+prices[4]+".00"; 
  document.getElementById("Price_C5").innerHTML = ""+prices[5]+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C6").innerHTML = ""+prices[6]+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_C7").innerHTML = ""+prices[7]+".00";

  document.getElementById("Price_T1").innerHTML = ""+T1+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_T2").innerHTML = ""+T2+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_T3").innerHTML = ""+T3+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_T4").innerHTML = ""+T4+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_T5").innerHTML = ""+T5+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_T6").innerHTML = ""+T6+".00";
  document.getElementById("Price_T7").innerHTML = ""+T7+".00";
}
```

Currently this takes values from html and when an item is selected the corresponding value is displayed for that option

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select Starter Kit</option>
<option value="299|built in|4 x A|1 x B| 1 x C|1 x12V Battery">Starter Pack 1</option>
<option value="399|built in|5 x A|2 x B| 1 x C|1 x12V Battery">Starter Pack 2</option>
```

//if I just have  299 and 399 respectively, when I select pack 1 I return the value 299, or select pack 2 I get value 399

// the value 299|built in|4 x A|1 x B| 1 x C|1 x12V Battery , I want to split so that when i select pack 1  I get, as currently I return "299|built in|4 x A|1 x B| 1 x C|1 x12V Battery"

```
299
built in
4 x A
1 x B
1 x C
1 x12V Battery
```

and I can recall these values back into my html document, so I need to split using JavaScript and the separator being |

these would then be recalled as sub values of the value, but I have no idea how to do this after looking at several possibilities.  Can anyone direct me in the right direction please.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl There's no need to be rude. Everyone is at different levels of experience.

Comment: are you using java or javascript to split the string?

Comment: since your code is in javascript, that's what I'll go with. You can google "javascript string split" and "javascript string trim" (trim is for removing spaces from a string)

Comment: Thanks I have searched and got this far, but the code i have tried the splitting on doesn't seem to work, so i am obviously doing something wrong.  so I split it into 6 parts, separated by | , then I need to recall the 6 bits individually.

Comment: cool got it, but very confusing searching on the terms as there was lots of complex stuff out there and I needed it simple.

so added these lines to my java, 

  var split = (document.getElementById("starterkit").value).split('|'); // splits my html value into splits[0] etc


  document.getElementById("Price_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = ""+split[0]+".00"; // returns values according to the html id
  document.getElementById("Value1_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = split[1];
  document.getElementById("Vaule2_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = split[2];

and so on, thanks this works.

Comment: okay alm,ost there, I am having problems with leading zeros on the total. basically I recall the split[0], as this is my price, this displays okay, it also displayed okay when the value was just a number and not seperated by |.  the problem now is a leading zero in the total at the end and I cant seem to get rid of it. any ideas, meanwhile I will soldier on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cool got it, but very confusing searching on the terms as there was lots of complex stuff out there and I needed it simple. so added these lines to my java:-

```
var split = (document.getElementById("starterkit").value).split('|'); // splits my html value staterkit into splits[0] etc at each |

document.getElementById("Price_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = ""+split[0]+".00"; // returns values according to the html id 
document.getElementById("Value1_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = split[1];
document.getElementById("Vaule2_Vstarterkit").innerHTML = split[2]; and so on, thanks this works.
```

Thanks for everyones help.